# Class use a function of another class that point to each other

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have following two classes:

```
#ifndef CLASS_A_H
#define CLASS_A_H

class B;

class A{
public:
  bool checkSomethingA();
private:
  int numA;
protected:
  B* classB;
};
#endif
```

and

```
#ifndef CLASS_B_H
#define CLASS_B_H
#include "ClassA.h"

class B {
public:
    bool checkSomeThing();      
private:
    int numB;
    A* classA;
};
#endif
```

in ClassB.cpp

```
bool ClassB::checkSomething()
{
    if (this->numB > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I want to call func `checkSomething()` of classB in classA but if i do it the this pointer (this->numB) will be null (obviously), but i dont know how to fix it.

In classA.cpp

```
bool ClassA::checkSomethingA()
{
    if (classB->checkSomeThing())
        numA == 100
    else
        numA == 0;
}
```

Comment: `ClassB::` / `ClassA::`??

Answer (score 0):

You can make the method static, so you can call it without an instance of ClassB.

```
static bool ClassB::checkSomethingA(){...}
```

Then you can call it by using:

```
ClassB::checkSomethingA();
```

Otherwise, you would need to create an instance of ClassB to call the method.

```
ClassB test = new ClassB();
test.checkSomethingA();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like the following:

```
class B;

class A{
public:
  explicit A(B& b) : classB(&b) {} // Constructor to initialize classB
  bool checkSomethingA() const;
private:
  int numA = 42;
protected:
  B* classB = nullptr;
};

class B {
public:
    bool checkSomeThing() const { return (this->numB > 0); }    
private:
    int numB = 42;
    A* classA = nullptr;
};

bool ClassA::checkSomethingA() const
{
    if (classB->checkSomeThing())
        return numA == 100
    else
        return numA == 0;
}
```

And then

```
int main()
{
    B b;
    A a(b);

    bool b1 = b.checkSomeThing();
    bool b1 = a.checkSomethingA();
}
```